# import HTTP_PROVIDERS in app.component.ts

Tags: angular

When I try to import the HTTP_PROVIDERS from angular/http I have this error:

```
Error:(3, 9) TS2305: Module '"projectname/node_modules/@angular/http/index"' has no exported member 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'.
```

this is my file content:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {GithubService} from './services/github.service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from  '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><Profile></Profile>',
    providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS, GithubService ]
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use >= RC.5 add `HttpModule` to `imports` in `@NgModule` instead:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  ...
})
class AppModule {}
```

Comment: for what I need `HTTP_PROVIDERS` and how to use that?

Comment: `HTTP_PROVIDERS` was replaced by `HttpModule` shortly before the first final 2.0.0 release.

Comment: I got it, but we do import for what?

Comment: `imports` in `@NgModule()` is to import providers to make them available in the root (global) scope, and all components, directives, and pipes of the imported module become available in the importing module. See also https://angular.io/

Answer (score 2):

What if i want to write an auth-interceptor using e.g.

```
import { provideAuth } from 'angular2-jwt';
...
bootstrap(App, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provideAuth({
    headerName: YOUR_HEADER_NAME,
    headerPrefix: YOUR_HEADER_PREFIX,
    tokenName: YOUR_TOKEN_NAME,
    tokenGetter: YOUR_TOKEN_GETTER_FUNCTION,
    globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type':'application/json'}],
    noJwtError: true,
    noTokenScheme: true
  })
])
```

First, there is no HTTP_PROVIDERS in @angular/http. Second, there is no bootstrap in @angular/platform-browser-dynamic

Everywhere you find simillar thing s when you want to write your auth interceptor, but nowhere it is written how to do it whith the released version of angular 2 :(
All examples are just not working anymore :( Can anyone tell me how to write an auth interceptor with hte RELEASED version of angular2, i.e. @angular/*:2.0.0